# How can standard cells of a process design kit have multi-Vdd?

Tags: digital-logic, integrated-circuit, physical-design

I was confused after reading the datasheet of a process design kit (PDK) where it says that the standard cells support multi Vdd.

How is this possible? Isn't Vdd fixed for standard cells? Since all the standard cells operate in saturation region, increasing the Vdd would not give any type of advantage in driving strength. What advantage would the multi Vdd support give?

Answer (score 0):

Increasing VDD will basically reduce the delay of the standard cell. Depending on the speed needed for your circuit, you can choose the VDD. If it is a very low speed circuit that you are designing, you can go for a lower VDD to save power (both leakage and switching). Hence a multi-VDD support is basically to give flexibility to the designer to save power.